# Uable to access Classes inside subfolder for private cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Hi i am trying to make a private lib with cocoapod .
Structured is shown in the image.

This is my podspec file code :

```
s.source_files = 'ModuleName/Classes/**/*', 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/**/*','ModuleName/Classes/viewController/Model/*'

  #specifying a folder as a resource will just create a reference to that folder in the Pods project
  s.resources  = 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/', 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/Model'

  s.subspec 'viewController' do |ss|
      # ss.source_files = 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/*.{swift}'
      ss.subspec 'Model' do |sss|
      sss.source_files = 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/Model/*.{swift}'
      end

  end
  s.dependency 'ModuleName/Classes/viewController/Model/','~ 0.1.1'
```

[image]

Can i get a podspec file example where i can make several nested folder that can remain even after import.

thanks